# Dealing with a string that consists of only space characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Genre = str(input(prompt))
GenreStripped = Genre.strip()
Length = len(GenreStripped)
while Length > 0:
```

Im trying to make a function that does not only accept ' ' spaces as an input, what are some other python functions to deal with ' ' as an input, because the strip() function does not strip '     '.

Comment: When you say "the strip() function does not strip ' '" are you talking about single quotes (`'`)? If so, why not just `GenreStripped.strip("'")`?

Answer (score 1):

`.strip()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, not spaces in between characters. you could use `.replace(" ", "")` instead if you wanted to remove every space

Try running the following to get a sense of the differences between these methods:

```py
print(" test test test ".replace(" ", ""))  # 'testtesttest'
print(" test test test ".strip())  # 'test test test'
```